# Integrate bootstrap 3 typeahead and tags input with objects as tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am having trouble integrating bootstrap 3 typeahead with tags input but with objects as tags. It works if I use only typeahead on input field, but if I integrate it with tags input then it doesn't work and I don't even get any errors which is really frustrating. Here's my code:

```js
var places = [{name: "New York"}, {name: "Los Angeles"}];
//this works
$('input').typeahead({
    source: places
});

//this doesn't
$('input').tagsinput({
    freeInput: false,
    confirmKeys: [44],
    typeahead: {
        source: places
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

If anyone has a working example of this I'd really appreciate some help, it can be typeahead.js instead of bootstrap 3 typeahead, I tried to use that as well and it works but then I have a problem where if I choose a suggested option from typeahead clicking enter submits the whole form instead of just accepting that option as a tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should attach the typeahead to tagsinput via the `typeahead` option! This is much easier (and what the [docs suggests](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)). Then, if you `map()` `places` to an array of strings it works :

```js
$('.tagsinput-typeahead').tagsinput({
  // other tagsinput options here
  typeahead: {
    source: places.map(function(item) { return item.name }),
    afterSelect: function() {
       this.$element[0].value = '';
    }
  }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gm3a1s9k/1/**

Notice the `afterSelect()`, [it is needed in order to clear the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379379/tagsinput-typeahead-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined).

Comment: @Mario_Plantosar Wonder why this answer wasn't accepted.

Comment: Well this is quite different from the docs, but very glad you posted this.

Comment: After selecting an option and removing it from tags input . it won't give access to create Tags input on free text entered while pressing tab or on mouse click event. Kindly give solution .

Comment: hey @SaurabhMehta, Thanks for the reply. Really cant help out of a vague description :) What version? What are you doing specifically, i.e the code and more. Can you reproduce the behaviour in a fiddle? I think you might be better off asking a new question with relevant code and a demonstrating example. Or perhaps, if you are convinced it is a bug, go directly and raise an issue at https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues ..?