# tagsinput & typeahead: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I keep getting this error when trying to use tagsinput & typeahead.

html:

```
<section id="examples">
  <div class="example example_typeahead">
    <h3>Typeahead</h3>
    <div class="bs-example">
      <input class="testing" type="text" value="nope" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

javascript:

```
var data = ['yes', 'yesyes', 'no', 'nope', 'yes again'],
  elt = $('.testing');

elt.tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: data
  },
});
```

I get the apply error after clicking on an item in the list. I also notice that the text I typed isn't removed.
I have searched for other similar issues but didn't find a working answer.

**note:** I'm using this plugin for typeahead https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead
 and this plugin for tagsinput http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 4):

I *guess*, but am not sure, that there has been made a bootstrap-tagsinput update which somehow broke the way it treats the "old" bootstrap typeahead. I have found two bugs, but not tracked completely down why.

**1'st issue**
<strike>The error "*Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined*" is raised in typeahead and is caused by the typeahead trying to target a undefined value. The issue is [**here**](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/452) as well. I have made a [**pull request**](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/pull/199) for this (click for details). Hopefully my suggestion will be merged, if not you can download [**this**](https://github.com/davidkonrad/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) forked repo.</strike>  The pull request is now merged into master.

**2nd issue**
When the nasty exception was history, I noticed that bootstrap-tagsinput not is cleaning up after a selection is made in the typeahead. The selection is made but the whole string or portions of the string remains in the input box. This can be solved by using a `afterSelect` handler :

```js
$('#someElement').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: data,
    afterSelect: function() {
       this.$element[0].value = '';
    }
  }
})
```

With these two changes, bootstrap-tagsinput and boostrap3-typeahead works as expected. See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bao3vk2m/**