# Issues integrating bootstrap-tagsinput, boostrap3-typeahead and Bloodhound

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bloodhound, bootstrap-tags-input

My fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bao3vk2m/1/).

I'm extending the example in [the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bao3vk2m/) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35489978) to work with [Bloodhound](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/bloodhound.js).

I'm prefetching the data using the following snippet:

```
prefetch_url='https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/cities.json';

var cities = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: prefetch_url,
    ttl:1
});

cities.initialize();
```

This is based on the example [here](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

I've modified the `typeahead` within `tagsinput()` to get and use the `text` and value fields appropriately.

I have the following problems:

1. The size of the textbox keeps changing.
2. If I type in the textbox, I receive an `Uncaught TypeError: sync is not a function` from the `bloodhound.js` file.

I'd like the textbox to populate based on the `cities.json`. Thus, if I enter *Amsterdam* and *Washington*, I should see `$("#myBox").val() = "1,4"`.

I think I may be wrongly mixing different versions of typeahead, but I've tried several combinations of JS files without any luck.

Comment: If I run your fiddle on Safari or Chrome there is no `Uncaught TypeError`. What are the steps to reproduce this issue? And could you please explain what do you mean with `textbox keeps changing`? Do you want the textbox to be fixed width?

Comment: Thanks, @gearsdigital. Yes, I want it to be a fixed width. For some reason I don't receive a TypeError anymore as you said, but the `cities` are not being populated in the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is a simple css fix. The following css will make your Textbox match the parent element width. If you prefer a fixed width instead just set a fixed value

```
/* match parent element width */
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 100%;
}

/* alternatively set a fixed width */
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 320px;
}
```

The second problems wa located in some misconfiguration. You missed to set the properties `itemValue` and `itemText` of the tagsinput plugin. I also  added a method which populates your selected cities. If you don't need this feature just remove the method `populateValues()`.

Surly there is some room to improve this implementation but this could be easily done by yourself, right?

**Edit:** After further debugging using a promise seems to fix OPs issues mentioned in comments.

You can find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/21fbf1L8/3/

Example Repo: https://github.com/gearsdigital/so-questions-38493752-

Comment: I'm not receiving any typeahead suggestions on Chrome, Safari or Firefox. Also, I'd prefer to be able to get a comma-separated list of IDs (like my original source) and not the actual tag name as the return value.

Comment: It works fine so far. Did you tried to write a city name like amsterdam? Anyhow, i've edited my fiddle to match your requirements (comma-separated list of IDs): http://jsfiddle.net/21fbf1L8/

Comment: it [doesn't suggest anything](https://i.gyazo.com/ba57e125234b67267cf9b906c94dbc28.gif)

Comment: Strange! Do you get any errors? Maybe it is an issue with your system or a security policy in your browser? Firefox, Safari and Chrome under OSX are fine: http://makeagif.com/vkjA5q

Comment: It could be an issue with your linked resources from github. github does not send a proper content type. Try to checkout this example repository which is using your code: https://github.com/gearsdigital/so-questions-38493752- You should run this on a server.

Comment: [...when Google Chrome implemented a security fix that prevents JavaScript from being executed if it has an incorrect Content-type.](http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/) This  is a possible explanation.

Comment: Interestingly, it works only after one reload, on both jsfiddle and after cloning and running your repo. If I hit `F5` then I can see *Paris* and *Buenos Aires*, and get typeahead suggestions for the other cities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118841/discussion-between-gearsdigital-and-jedi).